# max3232 disconnection suddenly - problem

Tags: stm32, serial, communication, rs232, max3232

Hi I use a Max3232 chip to connect the RS232 between the microcontroller(STM32F103) and an HMI, the problem is that sometimes this connection will be disconnected and no longer work, this may happen immediately or after a few days, I am so confused. Can anyone guide me?
The schematic of the circuit is in the picture below :
[image: MAX3232 SCHEMATIC]

Comment: How do you know the MAX3232 is the problem? Does it heat up? Does it work after reboot or power-down/power-uo sequence? Is it damaged and needs to be replaced?

Comment: @Justme When I put my finger on it is completely cool, sometimes it may work again, but I don't understand what makes it work or disabled.After the reboot, it still doesn't work, I replaced it several times and the connection is restored, but it's quite chance .. Is this because of a fake max3232?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/700995/edit) the question to include more details about the symptoms of ``the problem is that sometimes this connection will be disconnected and no longer work``. With the information posted unsure if the failure is (a) the MAX3232 circuit (b) the HMI hardware (c) the HMI software (d) the STM32F103 software. What debugging steps have been taken so far?

Answer (score 1):

There is one problem in the schematics provided.

The unused pin 10 is left disconnected, and unused logic inputs are not supposed to be left disconnected.

The problem may also be related to the LEDs on the pins, as they may load the outputs of MCU and MAX3232 too much, or otherwise cause problems due to photovoltaic effect and photocurrent, but unlikely.

One issue can be that the MAX3232 RX output has a 200 ohm resistor. It creates a voltage divider with the LED and LED resistor. The voltage might not go low enough for the MCU to detect logic low level properly.

The problem may also be elsewhere, like anywhere, in hardware or software, on either end of the RS-232 connection.

Comment: I think you are right, in my opinion the problem must be the LEDs, I had used the same schematic in another project without using LEDs and I did not face such a problem,  I will remove the LEDs and tell you the result

Comment: Do you recommend connecting PIN 10 to the GND through a 10K resistor?